# In Angular 2 is it possible to invoke a selector element when some other element is clicked?

Tags: angular

I am trying to invoke calendar popup of angular2-material-datepicker when some other element on page is clicked.
That is:

```
<material-datepicker>
</material-datepicker>
```

should be invoked when some text is clicked:

```
<p> click me to invoke calendar</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't find anything in api docs but after I checked the source of calendar I found out that there is an `@input` property that it's job is to show or hide the calendar.

`@Input() showCalendar: boolean;`

Just try to bind a local variable of your component to it and change this variable in your click event.
(I doesn't try it by myself so take a try and inform me if it worked)

Comment: Won't @ Input work only if there is parent- child relation in components ? Better Option is @ ViewChild

Comment: @ParthGhiya You declare a variable in your container component and pass that variable as input to calendar. `<material-datepicker [show-calendar]='yourVariable'>`.